# How does one show $(\lambda x . (\lambda y.x))yx \equiv_{\beta} y$ in lambda calculus?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

I wanted to show:

$$ (\lambda x . (\lambda y.x))yx \equiv_{\beta} y $$

the definition of beta equivalence is [on page 17 of these notes](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/7/75/CS522-Fall-2018-Lambda-slides.pdf).

I did a few attempts but got different things like $x$. I think my main confusion is how to interpret:

$$ yx $$

at the end. Does that mean we are applying $x$ to $y$ or that we are applying $yx$ to the lambda function $(\lambda x . (\lambda y.x))$? I tried both interpretations and didn't get anything that made sense.

I think I understand what $\beta$ conversion means (cuz I could follow the example he gave) but then when I tried doing it myself on this weird example I got non-sense.

Answer (score 5):

I will make my answer more sophisticated by using parentheses. The first thing to realize is that $(\lambda x . (\lambda y . x)) y x$ is the same thing as $((\lambda x . (\lambda y . x)) y) x$ because in $\lambda$-calculus application associates to the left, which means that $A B C = (A B) C$. As you can see, $x y$ does not even appear in your expression.

After that, I would follow Yuval's observation that it is impolite to use the same variable for two different purposes: the $x$ and $y$ inside $\lambda$'s are *not* the same as the outer $x$ and $y$. We should rename bound variables to get
$$((\lambda a . (\lambda b . a)) y) x$$
Can you do it from here?

P.S. Please stop pelting us with questions about $\lambda$-calculus that all look alike. Take them one at a time, wait for the answers, and *think* about them. It is likely subsequent questions will become redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an unsophisticated answer; undoubtedly more sophisticated ones will pop out in due time.

Let's change the leftmost $y$ to a $z$, to avoid confusion.

When you apply $\lambda x. (\lambda z.x)$ to $y$, you get $\lambda z.y$. When you apply this to $x$ (indeed, to anything at all), you get $y$.